# Why doesn't the splice method remove all the items from an array with matching property values?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove items from `orders[]` array where the `tableNumber` provided in the function parameter matches table_id.

```
orders = [
    {food_id: 5, table_id: 1},
    {food_id: 5, table_id: 2},
    {food_id: 5, table_id: 1},
    {food_id: 5, table_id: 1},
    {food_id: 5, table_id: 2},
    {food_id: 5, table_id: 3},
];

removeAllOrdersForTable(tableNumber: Table): void
{
    for (let order of this.orders) {
        let match = (order.table_id == tableNumber);
        match ? this.orders.splice(this.orders.indexOf(order), 1) : null;
    }
}
```

If I execute removeAllOrdersForTable(1), it still leaves some items in `orders[]` array with `table_id` of 1. When I console.log(orders) after the function execution, I still get something like the following:

```
Array[1]
0: Object {food_id: 5, table_id: 1},
1: Object {food_id: 3, table_id: 1},
```

Is this the appropriate way to remove multiple objects from an array that match an object property values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you remove items while you have a loop on the same array, there will be items that get skipped in the loop.

Why not use `filter`? It does what you need, and you can assign the result back to `this.items`:

```
removeAllOrdersForTable(tableNumber: Table): void
{
    this.orders = this.orders.filter(order => order.table_id == tableNumber);
}
```

The `filter` method creates a new array with the matches. By assigning that result back to `this.orders` you replace the original array, by the array of matches.

#### Mutating the array

In case you need `this.orders` array to keep its original reference, then you can use `splice` just once, namely by  removing all original elements and inserting the filter matches instead. But only do this if the previous method does not work because of other dependencies in your code:

```
removeAllOrdersForTable(tableNumber: Table): void
{
    this.orders.splice(0, this.orders.length, 
                          ...this.orders.filter(order => order.table_id == tableNumber);
}
```

Comment: that's what I'm gonna say

Comment: This filters items with matching results, but how do I remove them? I'm new to JS. Please mention the next step.

Comment: The `filter` method creates a new array, but when you assign that to the original `this.orders` (like I put in my answer), the other items will no longer be listed in `this.orders` any more, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
var _orders = this.orders.slice();
for (let order of _orders) {
    if(order.table_id == tableNumber){
        var index = this.orders.indexOf(order);
        this.orders.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you copied my answer

Comment: @VladuIonut I answered 9 minutes ago and you answered just 2 minutes ago, doesn't that tell us who copied who?

Answer (score 1):

```
   var newArray = this.orders.slice();
    for (let order of newArray) {
        let match = (order.table_id == tableNumber);
        match ? this.orders.splice(this.orders.indexOf(order), 1) : null;
    }
```